# Snowflake dashboards - one query on multiple tiles

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

With snowsight dashboards I often use the same query to visualise different things in multiple tiles but this means the query runs separately for each

Is there a way to manage the one query to run and apply to multiple tiles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each tile needs to have its own query to execute. So it's not possible to share the result of the same query, but if you run the same query multiple times, I would expect your query to use cached results (instead of re-processing, using the existing result).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results